magento246: getting wrong permission for category?
I have set category permission to deny for non-logged-in users and in the database values are saved accordingly.

but when I search product on front end it shows the wrong permission.
\Magento\CatalogPermissions\Observer\ApplyProductPermissionOnCollectionAfterLoadObserver


any idea?

I could not figure out why it was behaving this way, but created an alternate solution to fix this issue.

Pyaray/CatalogPermission/etc/frontend/events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_collection_load_after">
        <observer name="magento_catalogpermissions_"
                  instance="Pyaray\CatalogPermission\Observer\ApplyProductPermissionOnCollectionAfterLoadObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>


Pyaray\CatalogPermission\Observer\ApplyProductPermissionOnCollectionAfterLoadObserver

<?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Pyaray\CatalogPermission\Observer;
    
    use Magento\CatalogPermissions\Model\PermissionFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory as CustomerSessionFactory;
    use Magento\CatalogPermissions\Model\ResourceModel\Permission\CollectionFactory as PermissionCollectionFactory;
    
    class ApplyProductPermissionOnCollectionAfterLoadObserver implements  ObserverInterface
    {
        
        private ProductRepository $productRepository;
      
        private CustomerSessionFactory $customerSessionFactory;
       
        private PermissionCollectionFactory $permissionCollectionFactory;
    
        public function __construct(
            ProductRepository $productRepository,
            CustomerSessionFactory $customerSessionFactory,
            PermissionCollectionFactory $permissionCollectionFactory
        ) {
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
            $this->customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
            $this->permissionCollectionFactory = $permissionCollectionFactory;
        }
    
       
        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            $customerSession = $this->customerSessionFactory->create();
            if (!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $items = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection()->getItems();
                foreach ($items as $item) {
$isAllowed = false;
                    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($item->getEntityId());
                    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
                    foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
                        $permission = $this->permissionCollectionFactory->create();
                        $permissions = $permission->addFieldToFilter('category_id', ['eq'=>$categoryId])
                        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id',['eq'=>0])->getData();
                        if ($permissions) {
                            foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
                                if ($permission['grant_catalog_category_view'] == -1) {
                                    $isAllowed = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if($isAllowed == false)
                    {
                        $observer->getEvent()->getCollection()->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

